# insertion sort C implementation

Tags: c++, c

I implement insertion sort as:

```
void insertion_sort(int * list, int len ) {
int i, j;
for(j=1; j<len; j++) {
  int   key = list[j];
  i =   j - 1;
  while(i >= 0 && list[i] > key) {
    list[i + 1] = list[i];
    i   = i - 1;
  }
  list[i + 1]   = key;
  }
}
```

When I call this function like this:

```
int list[] = {5, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2};
insertion_sort(list, sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]));
```

it works fine. But when I declare the list as:

```
int * list = {5, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2};
```

It fails. I know there is some issue with how I am playing with the pointers, but can you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: This code shouldn't compile: http://ideone.com/QDO0rz or http://ideone.com/oi5Ik3.

Comment: With `int * list =`, it shouldn't even compile. So int* isn't actually pointing anywhere.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth They don't have to be strangers, but you _do_ want people who are not too tightly involved in the development to do code review.  It's probably the single most effective step to quality.

Comment: @JamesKanze: (Well, comment now deleted because I realised this isn't going to be fixed with the debugger!)  The point is more "asking strangers to do your debugging work for you is lazy", but it doesn't apply here...

Comment: @AntonKovalenko It certainly shouldn't compile in C++03.  C++11 added to the initialization syntax, and it's possible that this is legal there.  (I'm not familiar yet with all of the details of C++11.)  If so, however, modifying the "array" would be undefined behavior.

Comment: guys, I am using gnu C compiler.

Answer (score 4):

There are no issues, `sizeof` gives you the size of the parameter in bytes - the first one is an array, so it gives you the number of elements times the size of an element, the second is a pointer, so it gives you the size of the pointer...

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, `sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0])` no longer evaluates to the size of the array.